# What to do with old files of the SoftIndexFileStore in Infinispan persistent cache store?

Tags: infinispan

I have a clustered cache store set up with Infinispan (8.2.4 Final) using the SoftIndexFileStore for persistence.

The documentation states that if entries expire it's not possible for the Compactor to cleanup purged entries and the disk usage will grow overtime. From the userguide:

> When entries are stored with expiration, SIFS cannot detect that some
>   of those entries are expired. Therefore, such old file will not be
>   compacted (method AdvancedStore.purgeExpired() is not implemented).
>   This can lead to excessive file-system space usage.

Most of my entries expire but there are some which need to persist indefinitely meaning I can't simply run a cleanup job every once in while to delete all the data files.

How to deal with this wasted disk usage? After several weeks of running I see many files which haven't been modified in weeks. Is it safe to delete old files which haven't been modified e.g. less than a month ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; old files won't ever be modified again (they are written once and then considered immutable until removed). Removing them manually could lead to failures since these files are referenced in the index.

Regrettably, when the store is iterated and the entries are found expired, the `Compactor.free()` is not called, because there could be multiple concurrent iterations and we could end up calling it many times for single entry.

A proper solution would be implementing a periodic (or JMX-triggered) process that goes through old files, computes space occupied by expired entries and schedules files that exceed some threshold for compaction. This should go into [Compactor](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/persistence/soft-index/src/main/java/org/infinispan/persistence/sifs/Compactor.java). Please see [SIFS javadoc](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/persistence/soft-index/src/main/java/org/infinispan/persistence/sifs/SoftIndexFileStore.java#L27) for general design description.

If you're interested in developing this feature and you want to discuss that more, please go to [Infinispan forum](https://developer.jboss.org/en/infinispan).

Comment: So there is no simple way to deal with this increased disk usage right now I suppose. I will have to create some kind of procedure which stops one node, removes all data and index files and then bring the node back up so it joins the cluster and replicates all the data.

Comment: Still getting used to SO, didn't know about the 5 minutes rule of editing comments. Just wanted to thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, I have to admit that I haven't though about expiring entries much when designing the store. Please file an issue requesting this feature in https://issues.jboss.org/